# simplify the code that converts plain map to nested maps

Tags: groovy

i need to convert plain map with environment variables

```
    HOST_IDX      :"192.168.99.100",
    PORT_IDX_HTTPS:"9447",
    HOST_ESB      :"192.168.99.100",
    PORT_ESB_HTTPS:"8245",
    PORT_ESB_HTTP :"8282",
    OTHER         :"foo"
```

to a nested maps that in json looks like this:

```
{
    "idx": {
        "host": "192.168.99.100",
        "port": {
            "https": "9447"
        }
    },
    "esb": {
        "host": "192.168.99.100",
        "port": {
            "https": "8245",
            "http": "8282"
        }
    }
}
```

below it the code that actually do this but i'd like to minimize/simplify it...

```
def env=[
    HOST_IDX:"192.168.99.100",
    PORT_IDX_HTTPS:"9447",
    HOST_ESB:"192.168.99.100",
    PORT_ESB_HTTPS:"8245",
    PORT_ESB_HTTP:"8282",
    OTHER:"foo"
]

def x=env
    .collectEntries{[it.key.toLowerCase().split('_'),it.value]}
    .findAll{it.key[0] in ['host','port']}
    .groupBy( {it.key[1]}, {it.key[0]} )
    .collectEntries{[
            it.key, it.value.collectEntries{[
                it.key, it.key=='host' ? it.value.entrySet()[0].value : it.value.collectEntries{[
                    it.key[-1], it.value
                ]}
            ]}
        ]}

println new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(x).toPrettyString()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your initial keys would have the right order (`IDX_PORT_HTTPS` instead of
`PORT_IDX_HTTPS`), you could just set them with a "nested" put. So you could
split on `_` like you do already and `swap(0,1)` the first two elements.  Then
use that as path to set the value into a map.  E.g.:

```
def env=[
    HOST_IDX:"192.168.99.100",
    PORT_IDX_HTTPS:"9447",
    HOST_ESB:"192.168.99.100",
    PORT_ESB_HTTPS:"8245",
    PORT_ESB_HTTP:"8282",
]

// simplified nested put
def assocIn(m, path, v) {
    path.dropRight(1).inject(m){p,k->p.get(k,[:])}.put(path.last(), v) 
    return m
}

// split the keys and swap the first two elements to get a path to use
// for a nested put
println(env.inject([:]){ m, it ->
    assocIn(m, it.key.toLowerCase().split("_").swap(0,1), it.value)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is border-line subjective/opinionated, but given the problem as stated, why not just do this:

```
def x = [
    "idx" : ["host" : env["HOST_IDX"],
             "port" : ["https" : env["PORT_IDX_HTTPS"]]],
    "esb" : ["host" : env["HOST_IDX"],
             "port" : ["https" : env["PORT_ESB_HTTPS"],
                       "http" : env["PORT_ESB_HTTP"]]]
]

println new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(x).toPrettyString()
```